# how to keep navbar from shifting on window resize?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

How can i keep everything on the page the way it is so when window is resized nothing moves and just a scroller appears. 
I am using twitter bootstrap.

```
   <div class="container">
  <div class="text-center">
     <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">TierList</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Tournaments</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Team Maker</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Counters</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Builds</a></li>          
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give `.container` element fixed width:

```
.container {
    width: 900px;
}
```

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/3QLf5ThO7lwLdfQQCbuH?p=preview

Comment: that doesnt work my nav bar still winds up bringing the pills beneath the other one to show them all. and everything shrinks in size to fit.  is it due to bootstrap?